# MYSQL - Check if all group members have the same type

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
SomeID GroupID TYPE
1       1        1
2       1        2
3       1        2
4       2        1
5       2        1
6       3        2
```

What i want to find is, is there a `GROUP` that all of its members have the same type. I also want to know what is the type of the group.

For example

> group 1 have 2 types (1 and 2),  
> group 2 have 1 type (1) and also 
>   group 3 have 1 type (2)

How i can implement it in **MySQL**?

Comment: do you want a query on that?

Comment: yes, of course a query

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  GroupID, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT type) totalType,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT TYPE ORDER BY TYPE) TypeList
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY GroupID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1d24/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ GROUPID ║ TOTALTYPE ║ TYPELIST ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║       1 ║         2 ║ 1,2      ║
║       2 ║         1 ║ 1        ║
║       3 ║         1 ║ 2        ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: The problem with the solution is that i dont know which type i have and i want to know it too

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT `GroupID` ,`type` FROM `table` group by `GroupId` HAVING count(Distinct `type`) = 1
```

see [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b669/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╦══════╗
║ GroupId ║ Type ║
╠═════════╬══════╣
║       2 ║    1 ║
║       3 ║    2 ║
╚═════════╩══════╝
```

Comment: @AlexandraOrlov Glad to help .. Please feel free to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code, including with clause:

```
select GroupID, if(sumTypes = 1, 'true', 'false') as AllTypesSame from (
SELECT  GroupID, COUNT(DISTINCT type) sumTypes
FROM    testtable
GROUP   BY GroupID) as subtable
```

I have tested code successfully with following results:

```
GroupID   AllTypesSame
1         false
2         true
3         true
```